# SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON List In Database SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to have a list that I can identify in my entire database

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

Thank you and thank you for helping me.

Comment: Closest I found is this: [How do you check if IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or OFF in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637976/7586) and [Set IDENTITY_INSERT OFF for all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16044046/7586). The first answer says that `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set **per session**, and will be `OFF` for a new session, so you don't really have to check it - you probably know if you set it to `ON` on the same session, or you can create a new session.

Comment: I accept this too, but I have to be sure to list and give it back. Thank you in any case.

Comment: Your entire question seems to be a single statement and not actually a question. I have *no* idea what you're actually asking about

Comment: Nice trick with try and catch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700982/1683270)

Comment: Thank you very much. This page is a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT   'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' +OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)+ '  ON' 
FROM SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) not like 'sqlagent_%'
AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) not like 'queue_messages%'
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' +OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)+ '  ON;'+'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' +OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)+ '  OFF;' 
FROM SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) not like 'sqlagent_%'
AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) not like 'queue_messages%'
```

Comment: The thing that actually does this is that I can identity I'll turn it on. That's fine thanks and grateful.

Comment: If you want both statement together then you can check EDIT part.